# How to block incoming connections from one IP address?

Tags: windows-xp, security, remote-desktop, ip-address

I have found out that one IP address is trying to RDP to a machine.

I would now like to get XP to block all incoming connections from this IP address, and I am finding it very frustrating how difficult such a simple task could be.

How do I block incoming connections from one IP address?

Comment: @avirk That's to specify hostname to IP mapping on the local computer, for outgoing connections. He wants to block an external IP from connecting to his computer, an incoming connection and also a completely unrelated concept.

Comment: @Bob my apologies I misunderstand the question.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the Windows Firewall to block incoming connections on port 3389 from that IP.

Comment: Can you block individual IP address using Firewall in **XP**?

Comment: yes, that should be possible. I just tested on my Windows 7 and if I add a custom firewall rule I'm able to specify the incoming IP. On Win XP the UI is a bit different, but it should allow it. Have a look at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/843090 - you can specify firewall exception based on IP address.

Comment: Specifying an exception on the basis of IP address wouldn't work because I want to exclude one address.  The exceptions need to either allow all addresses or a set of specified addresses.  There is no way to exclude just one address.

Comment: You could turn this into an ALLOW rule. For example: ALLOW all incoming conections on port 3389 from all IPs, except 192.168.bad.boy.  PS: I think there should already be a predefined ALLOW rule in the firewall that allows RDP, otherwise it wouldn't work. You could tweak it to add the exception.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be way in the XP firewall to have an exception like this. The only way seems to be to open up a port to either all addresses or to a set of addresses.

Answer (score 3):

If an inbound connection is getting through your router/modem, it is already a potential threat to other systems on your network, or will be some time, once it detects a hole in your infrastructure.

Unless you have a very old hardware or a modem, I'd suggest first trying to block the IP on the firewall settings of your router.

Enter your administrative web frontend of your router (see manual for standard login and IP)
and enter the IP to be blocked in there.

If this should fail, then install/configure the Windows Firewall on your XP and do as [this page](http://www.ehow.com/how_5038640_block-ip-address-windows-xp.html) says.

**Precision strike**
*If your router is asking for an ip address AND a subnet mask to it:*

Subnet masking is for defining an IP range based on how many bits are to be allowed beginning from the right side of the IP address. In order to cater for a single IP address, the address mask is 255.255.255.255 or /32, depending on notation. If you need to define a range, study the [WIKI page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki).

**Carpet-bombing**
Block all incoming connections - This is already the default on most routers, when filtering is activated.
Then you can allow for selected IP addresses/ranges one by one.

Comment: I had a look at IP filtering on the modem but I didn't know what subnet mask to put for the source and destination IPs.

Comment: Subnet masking is for defining an IP range based on how many bits are to be allowed beginning from the right side of the IP address. In order to cater for a single IP address, the address mask is  255.255.255.255 or /32, depending on notation. If you need to define a range, study this page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4_subnetting_reference

Comment: Subnet mask is the same for ANY single IP address, which is 255.255.255.255

Comment: Interesting thing about my modem is that it blocks all incoming connections except for any defined exceptions or for NAT forwarding.  But for outgoing connections it allows all connections except for any defined exceptions.  So what I've done is define an exception for outgoing connections to the IP address.  Will that achieve what I want?

Comment: @GaryJones that should do it, please remember to mark the most helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to install a good firewall like [Comodo Firewall](http://personalfirewall.comodo.com/). IP can be blocked via  [IPsec policy](http://forums.eukhost.com/f15/how-block-ips-using-windows-3638/), however it will be hard to add more addresses and manage other rules. Also you may disable RDP as easiest way.